# Why is my right-aligned text lower than my left-aligned text in the header? (pure HTML)

Tags: html, header, alignment

I'm trying to create a small "menu" on the right where you can navigate to other pages, but for some reason, it hangs lower than the left-aligned text. I want them to be on the same level.

```
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <p align = "left">
      Test
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <p align = "right">
        <a href="testOne.html">One</a> |
        <a href="testTwo.html">Two</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    
  </header>
</body>


</html>
```

It gives this result:
[image]

I would ideally like something like this (same level with a black bar underneath):
[image]

However I'm trying to achieve it in pure HTML, without using CSS or whatnot.

Comment: You are using CSS "The style global attribute contains CSS styling declarations to be applied to the element." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style

Answer (score 1):

To truly do what you are asking, with **no** CSS:
I think you have to resort to using a table layout. Set the `width` attribute to `100%` (Note: The `<table>` width Attribute is not supported by HTML 5). Then use the `align` attribute of the `<td>` for the left and right text alignment. For the line underneath use a `<hr>`.

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">test</td>
    <td align="right">
      <a href="testOne.html">One</a> |
      <a href="testTwo.html">Two</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not in an inline tag.
`<p>` is a block element tag
adding another `<p>` creates another line, thus the nested `<a>` tags in the `<p align = "right">` appears on the next line

This is how your code is getting structured by your code above
[image]

Comment: I tried adding <div style="display:inline-block;"> </div> around the first <p> and the last </p> and it doesn't seem to work or not well. I edited the code in the OP.

Comment: Now I actually tried adding that same thing but around both <p>'s separately and it's at least on the same line but it completely ignores my <p align="right">. Updated my code in the OP.

Comment: Ok, I found my solution.
<div style="display:inline-block;float: right">

Comment: To achieve what you, best is to use flexbox for a fully responsive navbar

Comment: Drop a link here for reference https://codepen.io/stanlouis/pen/gOpxKEe

Comment: That's cool but I'm trying to achieve it without the use of CSS, pure HTML only.

Comment: I suggest you to look up what is style attribute you're using in your html tags and how is it different from CSS

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for whoever might be searching for this.

Adding the div style works for putting them on the same line but to make the left/right-alignment work, I needed to add ;float: right.

```
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <p>
      Test
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block;float: right">
    <p>
        <a href="testOne.html">One</a> |
        <a href="testTwo.html">Two</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    
  </header>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: That is not the right answer. You're going to add up write more than 80 lines of code to achieve a mobile responsive view, that can be done with flexbox in just 20 lines of code. I would not put this up as answer

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but what would be the answer in pure HTML form then?